# Using database vs file for static data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, file

I have a box in the rightbar of my website named "top users per week". So, for a week, the content of that box will not change. So I can store that data in two ways:

1. Using a table database (and update it weekly by an event)
2. Using a file and update it weekly with a cron jobs

Now I want to know, which one is better and has a smaller cost? I mean executing a `select` query is more optimal or opening a text file on the server using `file_get_contents()` and `explode()` it ?

Comment: As always in these cases, it is worth testing it and measure how long both processes take. Then you will know, for your own system. I expect the file to be much faster than the database, even if the database has all the data buffered in memory. But that's a wild guess, not a certainty.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, both methods will be fast enough for you. I would go for what is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This is depending on a lot of different factors, to name a few

- How many users are top users of the week? 5, 10, 100?
- How much load does the database genenerate currently? Do you only query the users or do you also handle login/log parsing/... with it?
- Which database engine are you using?
- Are you using SSDs or HDDs (only matters at large files)
- Which os are you using? (some cache files in memory)
- Do you use persistent mysql sessions?

I always try to store such data in database and add a timestamp to it in order to be able to also display data from the past or create statistics from it; this way I can also simply store User-IDs without the need to load data seperatly from database (e.g. `SELECT user.name FROM user, user_of_week WHERE user.id = user_of_week.user AND user_of_week.weekid = 120 ORDER BY user_of_week.position ASC;`)

You can try testing it for your specific case on your own - write a test script and load them 100 times while measuring time:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
// Connect to database here
$TestAmount = 100;
$OverallTime = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $TestAmount; $i++) {
    // Read current time
    $start = microtime(true);

    // Load data from database here

    // Get the amount of time it took
    $time = microtime(true) - $start;
    echo $i .': took '. $time ."\n";
    $OverallTime += $time;
}
echo 'Overall time: '. $OverallTime ."\n";
echo 'Average: '. ($OverallTime / $TestAmount);
// Close connection to database here
```

This will output something similar to this:

```
0: took 4
1: took 5
Overall time: 450
Average: 4.5
```

Repeat the same for files and compare.

When storing data in files you can also use something like JSON - which is way more easy to parse.